# React Native Xcode cant build m1 chip without rosetta

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-m1

Switched to macOS after years of using Windows.

Currently developing React Native apps and i face a build problem.
Xcode can build ios apps if it runs through rosetta and i want to know why and how can i use it without rosetta.
The same app can be builted using command **npm run ios**
I already tried **excluding arm64** and it does not help xcode to build.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on my M1 Macbook, but for me [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31941) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31480) helped. However for two of my colleagues has problems after going through these issues.

Comment: this helped me a lot, man. I've struggled a lot with setting up React-Native environment on new Mac Pro with M1 Pro chip. iOS build was constantly failing and, basically, install cocoapods in Rosetta terminal + Run XCode using Rosetta fixed the issue for me